# How/Why a JS function couldn't be executed in code but works fine in chrome console?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

I'm working on a JavaScript project with the timemap API: http://timemap.googlecode.com I want to set date limit on the timeline, after taking a look at the doc, I have a listener on my timeline scroll:

EDIT: yes, band is global variable define before the function where i'm when I execute this code

EDIT: If that can help, I'm executing this code from the head tag of my html page.

```
    band.addOnScrollListener(function() {
    if (band.getMaxVisibleDate() > band.maxDateLimit) {
        console.log("Too fare");
        band.setMaxVisibleDate(new Date());
    } else if (band.getMinVisibleDate() < band.minDateLimit) {
        console.log("Too fare");
        band.setMinVisibleDate(new Date());
    } else {
        console.log("Fine");
    }
```

At scroll, I have the good message switch the position in the timeline: "too fare" or "fine" but the line after seems to never be executed on scroll bun if I copy this exact same line in my google chrome console, it do the job well and center the timeline at today.

EDIT: I also try to do a `console.log` in the `setMaxVisibleDate` function and this one is shown in same case that my timeline position is redifine: when I call the method in chrome console. And if always in the console I type `band._onScrollListeners` it will show the above function.

I'm you'r gonna find answer just with those quick explanation but I just would like to know if some of you already encounter similar problem (and I'm sure you have) and by what could this be cause, no need to say I'm fairly new to JavaScript so it's maybe an obvious mistake I made but I can't find out.

Comment: is `band` a global variable?

Comment: if the log is executed, then the line after it is executed for sure as well. Only it might not work or work differently than when pasted in the console because of different scopes or timing.

Comment: Yes, it's why it's working in my chrome console

Comment: I thought it could be scope problem but if I completly remove this code from my files, then I copy/run it from the console way after all my page loading and initialisation, it's the same however in this case, this block and the test line are obviously executed in the same scope or am I wrong ?

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: No unfortunately, only my logs

Comment: "...the line after seems to never be executed on scroll..." did you try to debug it and check if the variables (all of them... including `console` and `band`) have the expected values?

Comment: console is define by google chrome (I guess) so yes it have the expected value and band have to when I log it in the console. Anyway when I run the same line on the same band variable in the console it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there was a if in the `setMaxVisibleDate` and `setMinVisibleDate` which allow the changement only if the user is not scrolling the timeline when it's called so I delete it and it works.

But I can't understand why the API's doc tell to call that method in an onScroll event if it doesn't make any any change when you're scrolling, that's completely silly or do I haven't understand something well ?